# Decomposing an integer into an array of integers by bit manipulation

Tags: ruby, integer, bit-manipulation

I'd like to write a method that takes an integer and a bit length and returns an array of integers corresponding to the bits.

For example:

```
decompose(100, 4)
#=> [4, 12]

because:

100 is 01001100 in binary
        /   \
      0100  1100
       4      12

decompose(123456, 6)
#=> [1, 8, 60, 0]

because:

123456 is 000001001000111100000000 in binary
           /       |     |      \
          1        8     60      0
```

Note: I don't need to worry about bit lengths that aren't exact divisors.

Comment: I don't think you have the right number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def decompose n, l, a = []
  n, r = n.divmod(2 ** l)
  a.unshift(r)
  n.zero? ? a : decompose(n, l, a)
end

decompose(100, 4) # => [6, 4]
decompose(123456, 6) # => [30, 9, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def decompose(num, len)
  num.to_s(2).chars.each_slice(len).map { |x| x.join.to_i(2) }.reverse
end

decompose(100, 4)
#=> [4, 12]
```

Or this:

```
def decompose(num, len)
  num.to_s(2).scan(/.{1,len}/).map { |x| x.to_i(2) }.reverse
end
```